# Unique Hash from struct

Tags: go, struct, hash

I would like to generate a unique hash from an array of structs. The order might be different but the values are the same.

Example:

```
type MyStruct struct {
   ID string
   Parameters map[string]interface{}
}

arr:= []MyStruct{MyStruct{ID: "test", Parameters: map[string]interface{}{"key": true, "key2": "value"} }, MyStruct{ID: "test2", Parameters: map[string]interface{}{"key2": "value", "key": true} }}
//The order is different even inside the Parameters fields

arr:= []MyStruct{MyStruct{ID: "test2", Parameters: map[string]interface{}{"key2": "value", "key": true} },MyStruct{ID: "test", Parameters: map[string]interface{}{"key": true, "key2": "value"} }}
```

In both cases the hash should be the same since the values inside the structs are the same.

EDIT: Basically the idea is to generate a unique hash for caching! I want to combine the individual hash of each struct!

Comment: maps are unordered by design. Use an array to preserve order.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Do you want to hash the **slice** (not array) of structs, or hash the individual structs? It might be better to ask why. Do you want to check contents for equality (regardless of ordering), or do you want to checksum? Please clarify.

Comment: Basically the idea is to generate a unique hash for caching! I want to combine the individual hash of each struct!

Comment: So you want the hash of a complex data structure that includes unordered data structures. The fastest way to implement this is to serialize your data (with fields sorted) and hash it using something large enough to avoid collisions. However, I seriously doubt your caching needs to be on the whole data, it's usually on a very limited subset (eg: someone queries a unique ID and gets a lot of data back. This means your cache key is the unique ID, not the data).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Feng has a point, the accepted answer doesn't work not only because there are no exported fields in the struct, but also the fact that the way MD5 hashes **does** have order significance, see [RFC 1321 3.4](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1321.txt).

Not sure on efficacy, but I've got something working by passing in the slice as bytes using `encoding/gob` and `bytes` representing a hash to use in `Compare`.

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/DtgWFb0vbIt)

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/gob"
    "fmt"
)

type S struct {
    K1 string
    K2 int
}

func main() {
    sa := []S{{ K1: "foo", K2: 1}, {K1: "bar", K2: 2}, {K1: "baz", K2: 3,}}
    sb := []S{{ K1: "baz", K2: 3}, {K1: "bar", K2: 2}, {K1: "foo", K2: 1,}}
    sc := []S{}

    a := Hash(sa)
    b := Hash(sb)
    c := Hash(sc)

    fmt.Println(Compare(a, b))
    fmt.Println(Compare(a, c))
}

func Compare(a, b []byte) bool {
    a = append(a, b...)
    c := 0
    for _, x := range a {
        c ^= int(x)
    }
    return c == 0
}

func Hash(s []S) []byte {
    var b bytes.Buffer
    gob.NewEncoder(&b).Encode(s)
    return b.Bytes()
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Maybe https://github.com/mitchellh/hashstructure could  help you. It consistently hashes struct but can be used with slices and arrays.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and
https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers and improve your answer. A link is not a valid answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://github.com/rxwycdh/rxhash/tree/master method `HashStruct`, which computationally hashes complex nested structures, to ensure data consistency. For example:

```golang
import "github.com/rxwycdh/rxhash"
type A struct {
  Values []int
}

a1 := A{Values: []int{1,2,3}}
a2 := A{Values: []int{3,2,1}} // unorder but content is equal a1

fmt.Println(HashStruct(a) == HashStruct(b)) // true
```

This is useful for detecting whether the contents of a structure have changed.

Answer (score -4):

You can do this by serializing the array to an array of bytes, then computing the md5 sum of the byte array. Since the md5 sum is the hashed **sum** of the bytes, the order will not matter.

To serialize each element of the array, you can use `json.Marshal`, which will work for any type of `struct`.

The hash function will look something like this :

```
func Hash(arr []SomeStruct) [16]byte {
    arrBytes := []byte{}
    for _, item := range arr {
        jsonBytes, _ := json.Marshal(item)
        arrBytes = append(arrBytes, jsonBytes...)
    }
    return md5.Sum(arrBytes)
}
```

You can run the working sample program [here](https://play.golang.org/p/IW1YKmWFlgU)

```
func main() {
    arr1 := []SomeStruct{
        {
            param1: "abc",
            param2: 3,
        },
        {
            param1: "def",
            param2: 5,
        }, {
            param1: "deg",
            param2: 0,
        },
    }
    arr2 := []SomeStruct{
    {
            param1: "deg",
            param2: 0,
        },
        {
            param1: "def",
            param2: 5,
        },
        {
            param1: "abc",
            param2: 3,
        },
    }

    fmt.Printf("Hash1: %x\n", Hash(arr1))
    fmt.Printf("Hash2: %x\n", Hash(arr2))

}

func Hash(arr []SomeStruct) [16]byte {
    arrBytes := []byte{}
    for _, item := range arr {
        jsonBytes, _ := json.Marshal(item)
        arrBytes = append(arrBytes, jsonBytes...)
    }
    return md5.Sum(arrBytes)
}
```

Which will output:

```
Hash1: d065fee603fdcf75115204ec65310e1c
Hash2: d065fee603fdcf75115204ec65310e1c
```

Comment: Perfect, I was looking for this: "Since the md5 sum is the hashed sum of the bytes, the order will not matter."

Maybe I need to start reading more about hashing algorithms :)

Comment: Because there is none exported field in SomeStruct, so the marshal result is same. If you change param1 and param1 to uppercase, hash result will different. see https://play.golang.org/p/J9mJqSnCvDC.

Comment: As mentioned before this answer is just plain wrong. For something like this to work the data needs to be in the same order, so you need to sort the structs first.

Comment: To add to how wrong this is, run it in the debugger and see that `jsonBytes` == "{}".  You could also just use a print statement for `jsonBytes`.  @MarcoTalento please remove this as the accepted answer.

Comment: Can anyone confirm that the JSON marshaller/encoder is guaranteed to be deterministic, even between versions? Will the resulting hash be the same even one year from now (with a future version of Go)?

Comment: Unfortunately this breaks when one of the fields on the struct is a map.  json.Marshal is not deterministic with maps